# pymysql close connection and clean port

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm making a really transactional script that is migrating data from one nosql db to mysql but after a like 2 or 3 minutes I get this message

> pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'foo.com' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")

I'm already opening and closing connections as soon as they finish (since the script is multiprocessing to get a better usage of the server resources) I already have something that waits between tries,
but rather than having a bandaid solution I would like to make my script better, is there a way in which I can make pymysql disconnect and clean the used port?

I'm using an aws ubuntu server for the migration, I'm already aware that ubuntu keeps the ports open for 60 seconds and I've already extended the range of ports to the max, the script is running on a pool of 15 concurrent process, the mysql server is aws hosted (aurora).

So far while testing the script that I'm using processes about 10000 records per second.

Update:
Missed a 0 on the amount of records per second

Comment: Do you need to connect to different servers on each try? or is it the same server? If it is the same server, you can reuse the connection instead of closing them again and spawning new connections on every insert.

Comment: It is the same server, I've already tried re using the same connection but it crashes after a while and I don't really remember the message I got but I do remember that it had something to do with the multiprocessing bit of the script (this was a while ago and I had to change my approach because of it) I've used this approach for some time and I haven't any issue until recently @ThuYeinTun